# how to add status bar / toolstrip control in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, statusbar

I want to add a status bar in bottom of DataGridView in C# winform, but when i add status bar in it, it overlaps the rows.

[image]

Comment: there is no reason to "integrate" the statusbar in the datagrid. what to do you want to do? populate status updates for changes in the grid?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add the status bar in the same container that also contains the datagridvie? Because I don't think that DataGridView supports children controls...

Comment: yeh! i want to add status bar/toolstrip in datagridview itself, where as datagridview supports the property 'Controls' i am adding controls in datagridview by 'Controls.Add()' method.

Comment: i status bar, i want to show no of records and current row no, and current sorted column name

Comment: please dont do minus mark, if you don't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Spring-Property of one of the status bar items on the left site of the ProgressBarto true.

Comment: sorry, you may not understand my problem, the problem is that status bar is overlapping on rows, i want it should not overlap on rows

Answer (score 0):

I qouted from your comment, you said

> i status bar, i want to show no of records and current row no

you must you use the `bindingSource` control and integrate to `bindingNavigator` so you can easy to show the *no of records and current row*

Just follow the link [BindingNavigator.BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.bindingsource.aspx)

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for reply, in the status bar there is some another things also will applies, which i cant describe here, if you know the exact solution how to add status bar or toolstrip control in datagridview then reply, this type of solutions i allready have, and i dont need this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In datagridview we can add controls, but it will overlap datagridview rows and columns. I have added status bar but it is overlapping on rows. Typically there is no ways to add status bar or toolbar directly in the datagridview. But here is a work we can do.

Add a panel on form add datagridview into panel and then add status bar in panel (outside of datagridview). then dock status bar as bottom and dock datagridview as fill. It will looks like you have a status bar in datagridview. This will not overlap datagridview rows anymore.